# Deploying angular to production with dist output is not working perfectly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When using "ng build --prod" and copying the dist folder content to my war (which is deployed to tomcat container) am facing a lot of issues. Like the routing which is giving 404 error when refreshing the page.

In parallel to my client app I have the rest app (as a Dynamic Web Project) which I can deploy on server (from eclipse) and changes that I do are reflected automatically.
I wonder if it possible to include my src of angular as part of this project and deploying the client side as well within the same process?!

It will save handling 2 separate projects, and dealing with building the app in order to generate the production output which is not working perfect as it in dev mode!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the useHash option to your router config. It will change your routes from `yourdomain.com/path` to `yourdomain.com/#/path` and avoid 404 errors.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { useHash: true }
)
```

This is the easiest to do so but you can also serve your front separately with an NGINX for example and force him handling 404 by sending index.html and keep the same url

Comment: Thanks Pierre. The routing is working fine now, but Iwant to ask if what I did is correct: 
I built my app with "ng build --prod --base-href ./",
took the dist folder as is and copied it to WebContent folder,
in addition I created another index.html under WebContent folder that is redirecting to the index.html inside my dist folder... but I have an issue with finding the images for example.

http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/dist/#/app/components/<comp-name>/assets/img/edit.png

assets is a folder setting under dist folder and it contains the img folder!

Comment: sorry I mean: 

http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/dist/#/app/components/<comp-name>
when I go to: http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/dist/assets/img/edit.png 
the image is there!

in the img src I used "/assets/img/..." - from dev its working.

Comment: I changed the src to src="assets/img/..." and it worked.

Comment: One more issue, I have a page that adding an entity then routing to entities list page... but the new entity is not shown till I refresh the page manually again!